# Whenever i'm getting image from gallery or via capture image in drawing view it rotates in LANDSCAPE mode

Tags: android, canvas

Whenever i try to get image from gallery or capture image and take it to drawing view on canvas at that time sometimes image gets in landscape mode on canvas. I want to set it in portrait mode as default.

Below is my code of drawing view.

```
    public class DrawingView extends View {
    Paint mPaint;
    //MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    //MaskFilter  mBlur;
    private int width;
    private  int height;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Canvas mCanvas;
    Path mPath;
    Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width =w;
        height =h;
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

I want to set image in layout view as below.

```
    String s= getFilePathFromURI(ReportNewOneActivity.this, Matisse.obtainResult(data).get(0));
                File file = new File(s);

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.e("OnActivityResult ", String.valueOf(file));
                    fp= new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
} else {
                    System.out.println("File Not Found");
                }
```

Comment: @Darush It didn't help me and its not duplicate. I want to set it on View not in image view

Comment: Where you want to set image can you specify it.

Comment: Please check the code I've changed in question. @MihirPanchasara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for your solution.

```
String s= getFilePathFromURI(ReportNewOneActivity.this, Matisse.obtainResult(data).get(0));
            File file = new File(s);

            if (file.exists()) {
                Log.e("OnActivityResult ", String.valueOf(file));
                fp= new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
                d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                //mDrawingPad.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);

                try {
                    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);


                    switch(orientation) {

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                            BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                            mDrawingPad.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                            BitmapDrawable ob1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                            mDrawingPad.setBackgroundDrawable(ob1);
                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                            BitmapDrawable ob2 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                            mDrawingPad.setBackgroundDrawable(ob2);
                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        default:
                            bitmap = bitmap;
                            BitmapDrawable obd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                            mDrawingPad.setBackgroundDrawable(obd);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    /*img_count = String.valueOf(requestCode);*/
            } else {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
            }
```